# Rails - Struggling with Correct Relational DB configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

I want to create a DB that defines any number of user created "Nodes" and allows any number of user defined "Connections" between nodes.

My knee jerk reaction is to create a Node Model and Connection Model.  Configure Node Model as has_many: connections.  However, I want connections to be directional "from and to".  Seeding would look like this:

```
Node.create( name:'n1' )
Node.create( name:'n2' )
Connection.create( from: Node.find_by(name: 'n1'), to: Node.find_by(name: 'n2'))
```

and possibly...

```
Connection.create( from: Node.find_by(name: 'n2'), to: Node.find_by(name: 'n1'))
```

Certainly not saying this is the best way to do this, just trying to give an idea of the structure.  So the question...

What kind of, if any, associations would I add to the Connection Model regarding the Node Model?  I'm thinking I'm over complicating this and maybe the right thing to do is have no associations in Connections regarding Node, but instead simply require and check for uniqueness of :from and :to for a new Connection?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't normally create an object and then load it back out of the database again: you'd normally just hold it in a variable, like so:

```
node_1 = Node.create( name:'n1' )
node_2 = Node.create( name:'n2' )
Connection.create( from: node_1, to: node_2)
```

I would avoid having a field called "from" as it's an sql keyword, and while this doesn't make it illegal (since rails will escape it) it will generate some confusing looking sql.  I'd do it like

```
class Node
  has_many :from_connections, :class_name => "Connection", :as => :from_node
  has_many :to_connections, :class_name => "Connection", :as => :to_node

  def connections
    self.from_connections + self.to_connections
  end

class Connection
  #has association fields "from_node_id" and "to_node_id"
  belongs_to :to_node, :class_name => "Node"
  belongs_to :from_node, :class_name => "Node"
```

You could then add other methods to make the creation of connections more simple, like `Node#connect_to(node)` or whatever.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider using a special kind of database:  http://www.sitepoint.com/using-a-graph-database-with-ruby-part-i-introduction/